# Linux Capture the flag programming puzzle

Tags: c, linux, binary, virtual-machine, disassembly

I am quite new in linux (only know the basic stuff). I am trying to complete a Capture-the-flag (CTF) style challenge, in a linux virtual machine. So basically i have a C program file and a flag. I have no access to flag. I can read the program file and run it. This the C code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void check () {

    int invalid;
    if (invalid) {
    printf ("Password invalid!\n");

    }

    else{
    printf ("Password accepted!\n");
    system ("/bin/cat flag3");
    }
    }
    void password() {

    char password [200];
    printf ("Enter the password: ");
    scanf ("%s" , password);
    }

    int main () {
    password ();
    check();
    return 0;
    }
```

I have tried debugging it and viewed the assembler contents but i can not understand how to capture the password in order to know the content of flag. I tried to crack the password taking help from this link, http://eliteinformatiker.de/2012/11/16/howto-crack-a-small-c-program-with-assembler But i am not sure if i can edit the binary file of the C program or not because in the given permissions for the c file i can only read it not write in it. So i think if i can not modify a c file how can i modify its binary (maybe i am wrong). At this point i am kind of stuck i have tried debugging it, viewed the assembly content but i am not sure if i can edit the binary or not.I am not sure what approach to take in order to capture the flag?

Comment: Where/how is `invalid` set?  I see it being used in the function `check`, bu I don't see how it is being set.

Comment: I am not sure about that. Actually i was also confused about this point. I have not written this code. I got this code. When i run it, it asks for the password in order to give me access to contents of flag. I do not know the password so now i have to find some exploit/backdoor in order to guess the password to gain access to flag. And i can not seem to find out any exploit.

Comment: If you can debug the program, you should be able to modify the comparison.  For example, invalid is a local variable, and as such is stored on the stack.  You should be able to change it's value prior to the test.

Answer (score -1):

disclaimer: I am using Ubuntu-12.04 and gcc-4.8.-2 and gdb-7.7.1 debugger.

I executed the program under the debugger till I entered `check` and single stepped to the if.  I then disassembled the code and looked at the assembly:

```
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function check:
   0x000000000040062d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040062e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400631 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
=> 0x0000000000400635 <+8>: cmpl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400639 <+12>:    je     0x400647 <check+26>
   0x000000000040063b <+14>:    mov    $0x400754,%edi
   0x0000000000400640 <+19>:    callq  0x4004e0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400645 <+24>:    jmp    0x400651 <check+36>
   0x0000000000400647 <+26>:    mov    $0x400766,%edi
   0x000000000040064c <+31>:    callq  0x4004e0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400651 <+36>:    leaveq
```

And I looked at the values of my registers (just showing the important ones):

```
(gdb) info reg
    rbp            0x7fffffffdf00   0x7fffffffdf00
    rsp            0x7fffffffdef0   0x7fffffffdef0
    rip            0x400635 0x400635 <check+8>
    eflags         0x206    [ PF IF ]
```

Next, I single stepped on instruction `(gdb) ni` and repeated the disassembly and getting the value of `eflags`:

```
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function check:
   0x000000000040062d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040062e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400631 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000400635 <+8>: cmpl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
=> 0x0000000000400639 <+12>:    je     0x400647 <check+26>
   0x000000000040063b <+14>:    mov    $0x400754,%edi
   0x0000000000400640 <+19>:    callq  0x4004e0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400645 <+24>:    jmp    0x400651 <check+36>
   0x0000000000400647 <+26>:    mov    $0x400766,%edi
   0x000000000040064c <+31>:    callq  0x4004e0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400651 <+36>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400652 <+37>:    retq   
 End of assembler dump.
(gdb) info reg
eflags         0x206    [ PF IF ]
```

Recall that the way the `cmp` works is that simulates a subtraction setting the flags as appropriate, which is what `je` then utilizes.  So this code will perform a subtraction of -0x4(%rpb) from 0 (setting the zero flag as approprate).  The jz will take the jump if the numbers are the same.

So I modified the flag register with the command sequence:

```
(gdb) set $ZF = 6
(gdb) set $eflags |= (1 << $ZF)
(gdb) print $eflags
$1 = [ PF ZF IF ]
```

Notice that the zero-flag is now set.  A single instruction set (`ni`) and take a look at the disassembly:

```
(gdb) ni
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function check:
   0x000000000040062d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040062e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400631 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000400635 <+8>: cmpl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400639 <+12>:    je     0x400647 <check+26>
   0x000000000040063b <+14>:    mov    $0x400754,%edi
   0x0000000000400640 <+19>:    callq  0x4004e0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400645 <+24>:    jmp    0x400651 <check+36>
=> 0x0000000000400647 <+26>:    mov    $0x400766,%edi
   0x000000000040064c <+31>:    callq  0x4004e0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400651 <+36>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400652 <+37>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Which is in the else block, and you should get the flag displayed.  (Note in my test program I commented out the line to cat the flag).

Comment: I understand your logic and i tried this. But instead of displaying the flag it still showed me that flag can`t be opened and permission is denied.

Comment: After setting the zero flag, it jumps to the else but when it comes to the instruction to call flag contents it displays that i can not open the flag. I think as do not have root access so that is why i still can not open the flag. I have to find some other exploit in order to gain access to the flag.

Comment: @sar drat... Looking at the program, the `system` command lead me to believe that the flag is in the same directory that the program is located in (notice that `system /bin/cat flag3` is a relative path, not an absolute path).  I would be interested in knowing if you can navigate to the directory where flag3 is found, and what it's permissions are.  I have to wonder if we are overthinking this, and if you go to the folder where the flag is located and just run `cat flag3` what the results are.  (probably permission denied, but you never know).

Comment: No i can not navigate to the directory and run the flag directly. I do not have permission to do so. The purpose of the question was to find an exploit in the code in order to access the flag. I think as the variable invalid is not properly initialized so have to overwrite it somehow (maybe a buffer overflow attack). My main issue is that i am totally new in linux so i have the info in front of me but i can not figure out how to do that exploit in order to access the contents of flag.

Comment: I think you are missing something here.  The trick with the debugger is, for all intents, changing the value of `invalid` so code execution goes somewhere else.  If we modify the value of `invalid`, we will end up in the `else` block just like with modification of the flag.  Just curious, when you modified the zero flag, what was the exact error that your got?  Also, if this challenge is publicly available, what is the URL?  Finally when you were debugging, where was the executable (i.e. in your home directory or somewhere else on the file system)?

Comment: When i modified the flag it showed the message that permission to access the flag is denied and it can`t be opened. This challenge is not publicly available, it was given to us as a part of our assignment. Executable was in the home directory...............Well i was able to solve it. I tried the buffer overflow corruption and overwrite the value of variable invalid. After overwriting the value, it jumped to the else statement and i was able to read contents of flag. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like this requires a buffer overflow corruption. Enter password longer than 200 chars and it will corrupt invalid from its default zero value?

Comment: I already tried that. It gives segmentation fault if password is longer than 200 characters.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Scant isn't safe because it stores characters up to the null character in the variable. Can you do anything interesting by using '\0'?

Comment: I do not have root access to edit the code. So i can`t do anything about scanf. I  have to find some exploit/backdoor to guess the password in order to know the contents of the flag.